# cucumber does not recognize my steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

```
Feature: Home page
As a HR manager of a company I am visiting the digipresent app for the first time
I want to be welcomed with a greeting 

    Scenario: User sees the welcome message
        When: he goes to home page
        Then: he should see the welcome message
```

This file is named as `features/home_page.feature`

```
When (/^he goes to the home page$/) do 
    visit root_path
end

Then (/^he should see the welcome message$/)do 
    expect(page).to have_content("Welcome to Present")
end
```

This file is present as `features/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb`

`$cucumber --require features features/home_page.feature` when I do this, the steps are not getting recognised.

```
Feature: Home page
As a HR manager of a company I am visiting the digipresent app for the first time
I want to be welcomed with a greeting 

  Scenario: User sees the welcome message # features/home_page.feature:5
        When: he goes to home page
        Then: he should see the welcome message

1 scenario (1 passed)
0 steps
0m0.023s
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no semicolon after when and then

```
Scenario: User sees the welcome message
    When he goes to home page
    Then he should see the welcome message
```

This should work